# Can I change the URL of a video, or upload a video to a specific URL?

Tags: uploads, urls, media

Let's say a video has been uploaded to:
https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/2017-12-21_XXX.mp4

But the URL has to be:
http://www.example.com/videos/12/2017-12-21_XXX.mp4

Is there any way to change the URL or an uploaded video file to exactly what you want it to be, or to upload another version and give it the exact URL?

A company needs the URL link for MP4 files to remain the same as they were previously. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0):

You just create a folder called videos/and any subfolders/ inside your cpanel public_html directory then move the video from from the wordpress upload folder to the newly created videos folder or any sub directory you want to put it inside the videos folder.

and thats it